# Get text inside an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, element

I am trying to get a text content inside a div using jquery. But it returns 'undefined'. Please someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here. this is my code.

```
<a><div class="exc_text">Some text here</div></a>


$(document).on('click','.exc_text',function(){
    var text = $(this).textContent;
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textContent` is a property on native elements, not on jQuery objects. `$(this)` wraps `this` (which is a native DOM element) in a jQuery object.

Either stick to the native DOM api (and go with `textContent`) - which is what I'd recommend:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('exc_text') {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
})
```

Or stick with jQuery if you have to (and use `.text()`):

```
$(document).on('click', '.exc_text', function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reselecting the element with jQuery which you don't need to do. Try this

```
 $(document).on('click','.exc_text',function(){
    var text = this.textContent;
    console.log(text);
});
```

The easiest way to solve this is to look in dev tools. All i did was break on the second link, and hovered over this, which showed me that it was an element so no need to reselect it...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.text()` instead of `.textContent`

```
<a><div class="exc_text">Some text here</div></a>

$(document).on('click','.exc_text',function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use .text()

```
<a><div class="exc_text">Some text here</div></a>


$(document).on('click','.exc_text', function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
});
```